# Add all rows values JTable data from another JTable on another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

How to add all rows values `JTable` data from another `JTable` on another `JFrame`?

I have 2 frames, the first frame for the first data table and the second frame to receive data from the table in the first frame.

Do you have a solution so that I can fill the table in the second frame from all rows of the table data in the first frame?

Like this:

```
frame1 fm1 = new frame1();
DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) fm1.tableorder.getModel();
try{

    int rows = model2.getRowCount();

    String getname = (String) model2.getValueAt(rows, 0);
    String getpay = (String) model2.getValueAt(rows, 1);

    Object [] data = {getname,getpay};
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tableordered.getModel();

    model.addRow(data);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

(Just an example)

Comment: Please share what have you tried already.

Comment: Move your data from the first JFrame to your model class, and then from the model class to the second JFrame.  By the way, your application should only have one JFrame.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)